# Checking for match between user input and dictionary key with multiple values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, object, set

If I want to check if the inputted parameter in the `checkPlayer` function matches a key in `dict1`  and return the entire object or a specific value for the respective key, how would I change this code?

```
dict1 = {'Messi' : ('Argentina','Barcelona'), 'Ronaldo' : ('Portugal','Juventus'), 'Robben': ('Netherlands','Bayern')}

def checkPlayer(plyr):
    for x in dict1:
        if plyr == x:
           print(x)

checkPlayer('Messi')
```

I am mainly confused as to why printing `x` would print the players name and not the whole object. How would I print the whole **object**, or more specifically, *just* the nationality or team if a match was found. Not quite sure how to access indexes in dictionaries using for loops, it's not quite as intuitive as lists :/

Thanks guys

Answer (score 2):

You are iterating over the keys of the dictionary and printing the *key* (which is the name of the player) if it was found. To get the value for that key, you can use the [`get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) method (which also allows you to specify a default if a key wasn't found in the dictionary):

```
dict1 = {'Messi' : ('Argentina','Barcelona'), 'Ronaldo' : ('Portugal','Juventus'), 'Robben': ('Netherlands','Bayern')}

def checkPlayer(plyr):
    print(dict1.get(plyr))

checkPlayer('Messi')
```

**Output**

```
('Argentina', 'Barcelona')
```

Furthermore, to check if a player name is in your dictionary, you can simply have `if plyr in dict1`; you don't need to iterate over all the keys. So your method can also be:

```
def checkPlayer(plyr):
    if plyr in dict1:
        print(plyr, dict1[plyr][1])

checkPlayer('Messi')
```

**Output**

```
Messi Barcelona
```

Comment: How would I change that code to print out the key and the values or just a specific value (Ex. 'Barcelona)

Comment: @CosmicCat Print the player and the value at the first index of the tuple (see updated answer)

Answer (score 1):

your object is a key:value 
the key is 'Messi' 
the value is 'Argentina','Barcelona'
however in your print statement you only print the name of object will will return the key only without the value
to access the value you may use get() or the index of the object inside your dictionary

to get your desire result use this :

```
print plyr,':',dict1[plyr]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code:

```
dict1 = {'Messi' : ('Argentina','Barcelona'), 'Ronaldo' : ('Portugal','Juventus'), 'Robben': ('Netherlands','Bayern')}

checkPlayer = 'Messi'
print (dict1.get(checkPlayer,'Player not found')) # 'Player not found' will be returned if checkPLayer is not in the dict1.keys()
#result --> ('Argentina', 'Barcelona')
```